# Sort Wordpress Archive by multiple oderby arguments in pre_get_posts action

Tags: pre-get-posts, 500-internal-error

Actually this private function in my function.php works, BUT: i often get Error 500 by the Server on the first load, often it renders AFTER reloading the page.

```
## change the sorting order on archive pages: order archive by title
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gpsp_change_sort_order');
function gpsp_change_sort_order($query) {
  if(is_archive() && $query->is_main_query()) :
    $query->set( 
      'meta_query',
      array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 'key' => 'ausgabe',  'value' => '', 'compare' => 'EXISTS', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' ),
        array( 'key' => 'position', 'value' => '', 'compare' => 'EXISTS', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' )
      ));
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value position' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'ausgabe' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  endif;    
};
```

Is anyone expert enought to explain me that error?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but you have a couple of issues here

Firstly, `is_archive()` should be an object of `$query`. You should also just target the front end with your function. Remember, `pre_get_posts` alters **all** instances of `WP_Query`, front end **and** backend.

So this line

```
if(is_archive() && $query->is_main_query()) :
```

should look something like this

```
if( !is_admin() && $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query()) :
```

I can't figure out your logic with your `meta_query` and your ordering. I'm really not to sure if your ordering will really work. You should have a real look at that as you are specifying one key and sorting by another

One other possible issue I can see here is, you are using the `OR` relation in your `meta_query`. You are retrieving post which have one `meta_key` or the other `meta_key`. What happens when there are no posts having one or the other `meta_key`. How will this influence your ordering and what errors if any will be triggered. Frankly I have not tested scenarions like this yet, so this might be a grab at nothing, but still useful to keep in mind

You might need to work in some check to make sure that a key exists before you try to `orderby` by it.